# External iPhone Cryptography Libs

Tags: iphone, cryptography

Are there any legal problems using external crypto libs in my iPhone application? I know that Apple has to comply to US cryptography export rules but do I as a developer have any responsibility? How does it work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use encryption in your app for anything other than authentication, then you'll need to declare it to Apple and you'll need to explain exactly what is encrypted, why, and how.

I think that's pretty much the most of it. It's then down to the export masters (I have no idea who actually manages this stuff) to decide if they will allow your app to be sold/distributed outside the US.